# Date and Time Format in SAS token

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-blob-storage

The format for expiration date and time in a SAS token from Azure is

```
se=2017-05-15T16%3A37%3A15Z
```

Here:

```
Year = 2017
month = 05
day = 15
```

What is hour, minutes and seconds here?

```
Hour = ?
Minutes = ?
Seconds = ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> se=2017-05-15T16%3A37%3A15Z

```
Hour = 16 (4 PM)
Minutes = 37
Seconds = 15
```

Date time value is URL encoded and `%3A` is the URL encoded value for `:`.

Also, please note that this date/time value is in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use PowerShell to retrieve the date. To do that, you have to *decode* the URL and pass the result to the `Get-Date` cmdlet:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
(Get-Date ([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode("2017-05-15T16%3A37%3A15Z"))).ToUniversalTime() | fl *
```

**Output:**

```
DateTime    : Montag, 15. Mai 2017 16:37:15
Date        : 15.05.2017 00:00:00
Day         : 15
DayOfWeek   : Monday
DayOfYear   : 135
Hour        : 16
Kind        : Utc
Millisecond : 0
Minute      : 37
Month       : 5
Second      : 15
Ticks       : 636304630350000000
TimeOfDay   : 16:37:15
Year        : 2017
```